# what i am missing to connect my C# code to MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql

im very likely missing some obvious setup, im using XAMPP following a beginner project tutorial to make database, however i am getting an error  **System.ArgumentException**: 'Option not supported. at

`private MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("datasource:127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=Csharp_Hotel_DB");`

i already did search how to connect to MySQL but found no different than what said tutorial did :

-add MySql.Data.dll as reference,

-`using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;`

-making empty table at localhost/phpmyadmin via XAMPP

and then test the connection with`if(table.Rows.Count > 0) {MessageBox.Show("Yes");} else {MessageBox.Show("No");}` assigned to a button. the program works but clicking the button give error message above.

Comment: Can you provide the complete exception

Comment: Where did you get those MySql parameters from? They look WRONG. Generally connectionstring parameters are NOT LOWER CASE. Also https://www.connectionstrings.com/ says that the parameters are totally diffferent. Like not even funny different- DataSource is more like an ODBC name, not a native name, as parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the example I found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connections-string.html) (and an additional resource I often consult [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/) for different RDBMSs I encounter), the parameters in your connection string are mis-named:

```
datasource:127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=Csharp_Hotel_DB
```

It should be:

```
Server=127.0.0.1;Port=3306;Uid=root;Pwd=;Database=Csharp_Hotel_DB
```

It looks like you may be formatting the connection string based on MS SQL Server standards instead.  Most C# examples you find online will likely have that since it's the same vendor.  But the connection string depends on the RDBMS, not on the language connecting to it.  Which in this case is MySQL.

Comment: More detail: The go to reference for ALL things connectionstring related is at https://www.connectionstrings.com/